# Use jq to extract sublist into a single line

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, jq

From,

```
jq '.DistributionList.Items[] | select(.Aliases.Items != null) | .Id + "," + .DomainName' << EOF
{
"DistributionList": {
    "Items": [
        {
        "Id": "EG3MOA",
        "Status": "Deployed",
        "LastModifiedTime": "2022-12-03T19:32:35.007000+00:00",
        "DomainName": "a***.cloudfront.net",
            "Aliases": {
                "Quantity": 1,
                "Items": [
                "a.domain.tld",
                "b.domain.tld"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
        "Id": "EG3MOB",
        "Status": "Deployed",
        "LastModifiedTime": "2022-12-03T19:32:35.007000+00:00",
        "DomainName": "b***.cloudfront.net",
            "Aliases": {
                "Quantity": 1,
                "Items": [
                "c.domain.tld",
                "d.domain.tld"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
    }
}
EOF
```

It yields:

```
"EG3MOA,a***.cloudfront.net"
"EG3MOB,b***.cloudfront.net"
```

How would I also get the `Alias Items, so that I have:

```
"EG3MOA,a***.cloudfront.net,'a.domain.tld,b.domain.tld'"
"EG3MOB,b***.cloudfront.net,'c.domain.tld,d.domain.tld'"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are struggling to enclose an apostrophe `'` with JSON string quotes `"` withing a jq filter enclosed again by apostrophes, you can use the codepoint notation instead: `\u0027`

```bash
jq '… | "\(.Id),\(.DomainName),\u0027\(.Aliases.Items | join(","))\u0027"'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/0Go4AXZmA_q)

Comment: great, thanks, this is also cool to know